# Batch class finish method not executing on REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG error

Tags: apex, batch, asynchronous

I intended to send an email to the users when the batch class fails due to any reason. I had placed my logic in the finish method. However, my batch class is failing for the reason :

[REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG] Your request was running for too long, and has been stopped.

The finish method doesn't gets executed at all in this scenario. How can I make sure that email is sent in this scenario? Should I try having this logic in a catch block placed at the start method?

Comment: These are limit exceptions `REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG` which your `try` `catch` wont be able to handle.

Your start method should return result in 1 minute, otherwise this may come. So try to make the query selective, or else limit the number of record the start method is fetching.

Comment: @NagendraSingh but there should be a way to notify even if these limit exceptions occurs during the batch execution?

Comment: subscribe to platform event [BatchApexErrorEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_batchapexerrorevent.htm)